# Configure DevC++ with OpenCV 3.1

Tags: opencv, dev-c++

I have downloaded OpenCV 3.1 from their site and I want to use it in DevC++. I have tried to search on Google but I find only instructions for using OpenCV 2.0 with DevC++.

I read there I need to configure something in DevC++ to make OpenCV working with him.

Instructions for DevC++ with OpenCV 2.0 are here: http://rsgibson.public.iastate.edu/HCI575/Devcpp_OpenCV.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compiled source code of opencv, the ide configurations are the same.you have to add include directory's path,lib files'path and lib files which you will need.If you want, you can add bin directory's path to Environment Variables Path to reach them from every where.Or, you can add its path to 'Binaries' part.

Notice that DevC++ use mingw compiler, so opencv source has to be compiled with mingw.